# Eclipse "New Android remote device"?

Tags: android, eclipse, device

New to Eclipse, programming, and Stack Overflow in general, but does this feature allow me to use my phone to test my app directly? If so, how do I use it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! First, I would invite you to take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to have a better understanding on how this platform works. Second, Eclipse is no longer the recommended IDE for Android development: while it is still possible to use it, Android Studio is the best choice. Last, it is possible to debug and test your app on your physical device.

Comment: Eclipse has been discontinued as the Android development IDE a long time ago.
The Android plugin for Eclipse is not longer supported/maintained. 
Android Studio is the IDE of choice for Android development. 
If you insist on using Eclipse, which might technically still be possible, don't expect too much advice on that from here or elsehwere.

Comment: If you are new to Android development, you should definitely install Android Studio. You also need to become familiar with the [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/index.html). In particular, your question is already answered [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use your phone to test your apps. Firstly, you'll need to [enable developer options on your phone](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html), and then enable **USB Debugging**.

> To access these settings, open the Developer options in the system Settings. On Android 4.2 and higher, the **Developer options** screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to **Settings > About** phone and tap **Build number** seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

When you go to run your app, you will be given the option of currently available devices. Select your phone from that list, and your app will be deployed to it.

As a side note, [Google dropped support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) for eclipse in 2015. I'd recommend using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) for development instead.